# Cannot compile gegl when trying to compile Gimp

Tags: git, compiler-errors, gimp, gegl

I am trying to compile Gimp version 2.10 using the git source and [this method](https://www.gimp.org/source/howtos/gimp-git-build.html). I am a Gentoo user of many years experience, so not a beginner at compiling.
Gentoo Portage has version 2.8 but 2.10 looks really good. I am a keen photographer.

OK dependencies.... I need babl, gegl and pango because the installed versions are not late enough.
As per the above instructions I have compiled installed babl in $HOME/gimp-git/ and have an environment set up as this in the file $PREFIX/share/config.site

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/gimp-git"
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /usr/bin/"
```

I have issued the command

```
source $PREFIX/share/config.site
```

Now when I try an compile gegl with

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=$PREFIX
```

No problem with this, so I issue the 'make' command and that throws an error

```
<--- snip --->
gegl-tile-source.h:23:23: fatal error: babl/babl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <babl/babl.h>
```

Well that file is in

```
$PREFIX/include/babl-0.1/babl/babl.h
```

I have even put it here as well, but same error

```
include/babl/babl.h
```

Any ideas on how I can get the gegl build to find babl.h file would be much appreciated?

OK Since I wrote this I have added this to my $PREFIX/share/config.site file

```
export BABL_CFLAGS="$PREFIX/bin -I $PREFIX/include/babl-0.1/"
export BABL_LIBS="$PREFIX/lib/"
```

and the compiling proceeds until this:

```
gcc: warning: /home/francis/gimp-git/bin: linker input file unused because linking not done
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_with_space'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_get_n_components'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_get_space'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_get_type'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_get_bytes_per_pixel'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_type'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_init'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_model'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_process'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_ticks'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_get_name'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_exit'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_has_alpha'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_process_rows'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_exists'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_fish'
./.libs/libgegl-0.4.so: undefined reference to `babl_format_get_model'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
linking of temporary binary failed: Command '['/bin/sh', '../libtool', '--mode=link', '--tag=CC', '--silent', 'gcc', '-o', '/home/francis/FG-Docs/Downloads/gimpDeps/gegl-0.4.6/gegl/tmp-introspectomm_pwos/Gegl-0.4', '-export-dynamic', '-g', '-Ofast', '-mmmx', '-msse', '-ftree-vectorize', '-ffast-math', '-Wall', '-Wdeclaration-after-statement', '-Wmissing-prototypes', '-Wmissing-declarations', '-Winit-self', '-Wpointer-arith', '-Wold-style-definition', 'tmp-introspectomm_pwos/home/francis/FG-Docs/Downloads/gimpDeps/gegl-0.4.6/gegl/tmp-introspectomm_pwos/Gegl-0.4.o', '-L.', 'libgegl-0.4.la', '-lgio-2.0', '-lgobject-2.0', '-Wl,--export-dynamic', '-lgmodule-2.0', '-pthread', '-lglib-2.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
make[3]: *** [/usr/share/gobject-introspection-1.0/Makefile.introspection:160: Gegl-0.4.gir] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/francis/FG-Docs/Downloads/gimpDeps/gegl-0.4.6/gegl'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:906: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/francis/FG-Docs/Downloads/gimpDeps/gegl-0.4.6/gegl'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:635: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/francis/FG-Docs/Downloads/gimpDeps/gegl-0.4.6'
make: *** [Makefile:542: all] Error 2
```

So I am a bit stuck again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows.
I am using Gentoo and discovered an 'ebuild' for gimp-2.10.4 so uninstalled gimp-2.8 and installed the ebuild gimp-2.10.4 instead